# Solving large-scale stochastic mixed integer program

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

What are some methods or algorithms for solving large-scale stochastic mixed-integer optimization problem that runs on an hourly dataset for a year? Do we employ some kind of decomposition? (the problem in consideration is not bilevel)

Comment: This is a highly vague question and it's unlikely you're going to get much in the way of a response without giving more information about your model.

Comment: I am actually looking for general ways/guidelines to tackle these types of problems that are hard to solve even with a large optimality gap but do have an optimal solution.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com